# How to make a timer using Thread.sleep() while waiting for console input?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to write a program that asks simple questions with a time limit on them.

So far I have the following:

```
public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
    Thread thread = new Thread();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("1. What is 1+1?");
    System.out.println("a. 2\tb. Cannot Be.\tc. 3\td. All of the above."); 
    String question1 = scan.next();
    for(int i = 3; i>=0; i--){
        System.out.print("\b"+i);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

This properly asks the question and takes the answer, but it doesn't put a time limit on input and counts down from 3 to 0 *after* the input is given. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: let me know if the below answer helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using a little bit of black multithreading magic.

First, you'll need two threads like this:

```
Thread thread1 = Thread.currentThread();
Thread thread2 = new Thread(() -> {
    try {
        for (int seconds = 3; seconds > 0; seconds--) {
            System.out.println(seconds+" second"+(seconds == 1 ? "s" : "")+" left");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        System.out.println("Time's up!");
        thread1.stop();
    }catch(InterruptedException weCanIgnoreThisException){}
});
```

where `thread1` is the thread that asks the question and `thread2` is the countdown.

Then what is left is to ask the question. **Don't forget to `start()` `thread2` before asking for input and to `stop()` it after receiving the input!**

```
System.out.println("1. What is 1+1?");
System.out.println("a. 2\tb. Cannot Be.\tc. 3\td. All of the above.");
thread2.start();
String answer = scan.next();
thread2.stop();
```

---

Alright, so here's why I used the deprecated method `Thread#stop()`.

[The official documentation of `java.lang.Thread`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#stop--) explains why is `stop()` deprecated and what circumstances make it screw up programs:

> Stopping a thread with Thread.stop causes it to unlock all of the monitors that it has locked (as a natural consequence of the unchecked `ThreadDeath` exception propagating up the stack). If any of the objects previously protected by these monitors were in an inconsistent state, the damaged objects become visible to other threads, potentially resulting in arbitrary behavior.

In short, if a thread is `stop()`ped while it's locked on an object using a `synchronized` block or method, the lock on the object is released in a dangerously abrupt manner. Since asking multiple choice questions and placing a time limit on input doesn't require a thread to be `synchronized` on something, we can ignore this.

Comment: Thank you sir.. 
but I want to know what's the use of this object "->"? :)

Comment: (seconds == 1 ? "s" : "") and this one. :D

Comment: @WenCy `() -> {enter code here}` is a [lambda expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) (basically an anonymous class that implements an interface (in this case, [`java.lang.Runnable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html))) and `seconds == 1 ? "s" : ""` is a [ternary expression](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:)

Answer (score 0):

I would create separate functions to call during the loop, so you don't have a long winded declaration of global variables and such. If you need to control what is called randomly, then you can put a rand in a function and use one global that way, or you can simply put them in a order you want it to be called and completed as.

Answer (score 0):

As you rightly guessed, you need two separate threads running like in the below explanation & code.

The below explanation will provide you more details on what and how you need to do with the two threads.

(1) **Thread 1:** `Timer` thread (Inner class implements Runnable) runs in a separate thread and counts the seconds while waiting for the user's input. Once user enters the input this thread needs to be stopped using a signal (`stopTimer` variable acts as a signal), ensure that `stopTimer` variable is volatile (to receive the data written by Thread2), otherwise this thread will wait infinitely.

(2) **Thread 2**: This is the `main thread` which waits for the user's input. Once the user inputs the data, this main thread signals to stop the Timer thread using a separate method call - `signalStopTimer()`

```
public class TimerTest {    

        public static class Timer implements Runnable {

            private volatile boolean stopTimer = false;

            private long timerMilliSeconds =0;

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while(!stopTimer) {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        timerMilliSeconds = timerMilliSeconds+1000;
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            public void signalStopTimer() {
                stopTimer = true;
            }

            //this method will be helpful to find the elapsed time in seconds
            public long getTotalTimeInSeconds() {
                return timerMilliSeconds/1000;
            }

        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {

                 TimerTest.Timer timer = new TimerTest.Timer();
                 //Start the Timer Thread now
                 Thread thread = new Thread(timer);
                 thread.start();

                 Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

                System.out.println("1. What is 1+1?");
                System.out.println("a. 2\tb. Cannot Be.\tc. 3\td. All of the above."); 
                String input = scan.next();

                //received the input, signal to stop timer
                timer.signalStopTimer();
                System.out.println(" input is:"+input+" seconds");
                System.out.println(" total time :"+timer.getTotalTimeInSeconds());


        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you only need to count the time it took until user put his input, the better way and the easiest way is to use System.currentTimeMillis().

before the scan code you can save the current time in a variable (Long), then in while loop (when the loop condition will be stopped when the user put his input) in the end of the loop just save the same way mentioned above the current time in millisecond and then all left is subtraction.

if this is your direction let me know i can supply a code for that ;)